# How to update View on Android with fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to change color of a TabbedActivity, by the position of the current
page of the Fragment. The problem is that is seems not to work properly, because the color is always the case 2. Here is the TabbedActivity:

```
    package com.ismanettone.fantacalcioandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "pos";
        private int mPosition;

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mPosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome,
                    container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewProva);
            Log.i("position", mPosition + "");
            switch (mPosition) {
            case 0:
                textView.setText("Hello0");
                rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            case 1:
                textView.setText("Hello1");
                rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            case 2:
                textView.setText("Hello2");
                rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem, is that the text and the background color, doesn't change, while from the smartphone, there is the effect of swipe. What do you think about ?

Here is the layout for the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="myContext$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <requestFocus />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewProva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

What is the problem in my code ?

Comment: Are you getting titles for tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re missing a `break` in each switch case.

The following should work as expected:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome,
    container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProva);
    Log.i("position", mPosition + "");
    switch (mPosition) {
        case 0:
            textView.setText("Hello0");
            rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 1:
            textView.setText("Hello1");
            rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case 2:
            textView.setText("Hello2");
            rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            break;
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: You're right ! I'm very stupid ! Sorry for that stupid error, but I don't use switch, but with Android sometimes it is required !